# Is it possible to use BluetoothSerial to connect two esp32 together?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, wifi, esp32

I try to monitor some sensor for my plants. I have the following hardware :

- A mqtt server running on a raspberry pi
- An esp32 outside that collect value of a sensor
- Another esp32 which is supposed to be connected to the one outside and that collect the value send by the esp32 to transmit it on the server through MQTT.

Everything works fine for the MQTT part but i cannot connect both device through bluetooth. I mean it's working but only when i try to collect information on my phone with an app, idem to write data. Here's the code for the server part. I removed the global variable with the password ofc :)

```c
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200);
      SerialBT.begin("ESP32_server"); //Bluetooth device name
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
      
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(1000);
      }
      client.setServer(mqttServer, mqttPort);
    
      while (!client.connected()) {
        Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT...");
        if (client.connect("ESP32Client")){
          Serial.println("Connected to MQTT!");
        } 
        else{
          Serial.print("MQTT connection failed, rc=");
          Serial.println(client.state());
          delay(1000);
        }
      }
    }
    
    void loop() {
      if (SerialBT.available()) {
        String bytesRead = SerialBT.readString();  // Use readString() to get a complete string
        Serial.println(bytesRead);
        client.publish("esp32/data", bytesRead.c_str());  // Convert String to char array using c_str()
      }
      client.loop();  // Important for handling MQTT messages
    }
```

And here's the part for the emitter :

```c
#include <BluetoothSerial.h>

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
const int delay_seconds = 60000; // delay at which data is read from GPIO
const int delay_minutes = delay_seconds * 2; // delay at which data is read from GPIO
const int himidityPin   = 34;  

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(115200);
   SerialBT.begin("ESP32_sender"); //Bluetooth device name
   Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
}

void loop() {
  int valueSensor = analogRead(himidityPin);
  char buffer[12];  // Buffer to hold the string representation of the value
  itoa(valueSensor, buffer, 10);  // Convert integer to strin
  SerialBT.println(buffer);
  delay(1000);
  delay(delay_minutes);
}
```

Again this work with my phone but i don't manage to connect both esp32 together. I took a look into BLE but it seems more annoying to use and I'd like to know if it's not possible with bluetooth, why not.
Thanks !